# Data analysis with Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to summarize the data in the following Excel table about school enrolment by District and by Gender using a chart in Excel.

[the excel table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Knr5g.png)

The raw data is pasted below:

```
    Enrollment (B- boys, G- girls)                                          
  District Name Grade 1     Grade 2     Grade 3     Grade 4     Grade 5     Grade 6 
    B1  G1  B2  G2  B3  G3  B4  G4  B5  G5  B6  G6
District1   40  41  5   8   6   15  0   0   0   0   0   0
District2   43  31  8   2   6   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
District3   35  20  8   11  8   10  5   3   4   1   4   1
District4   40  14  22  19  15  9   15  2   0   0   0   0
District5   28  9   7   3   10  5   3   9   0   0   0   0
District6   10  29  3   10  0   0   4   8   8   6   12  2
District7   28  50  5   17  3   6   6   3   0   0   0   0
District8   11  4   2   11  8   3   0   0   0   0   0   0
District9   14  16  16  13  13  11          14  16      
District10  21  16  9   13  10  11          14  12
```

Comment: Have you tried to use a Pivot Table?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. We are not a script writing service. We expect users to tell us what they have tried so far (including any scripts they are using) and where they're stuck so that we can help with specific problems. Questions that only ask for scripts are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: The chart is already a summary by district and gender.  Do you mean you want to consolidate the grade detail?  Have you looked at just adding up the six B columns and copying the formula to add up the G columns?  That's pretty trivial.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

1. Click Autosum located on top right.
2. Hold down "Ctrl" and select the B cells
3. Copy formula down.
4. Repeat for Girls.

Stay in school.